# How can I get Column B's value based on Column A matching a given value in a datatable?

Tags: .net-3.5, lambda, datatable

I want to get the value for Column B in the first row I find with Column A = "123".

I tried:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["value"].ToString() == "123").ToString();
```

But I'm getting **Expression cannot contain lambda expressions**.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I'm basically looking for the SQL equivalent of:

```
Select ColumnB
From MyTable
Where ColumnA = '123'
```

For the datatable using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`FirstOrDefault` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx):

```
var foundRow = dataTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(row => string.Equals (row["ColumnA"].ToString(), "123", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ));
if (foundRow != null) {
    // We found a match, do something with it.
    var colBValue = foundRow["ColumnB"].ToString(); 
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` returns the first element that matches a specified criteria, which in this case looks for the string "123" in the [ColumnA] column in your DataTable.  If no element matches the criteria, `FirstOrDefault` returns the object's default value which for DataTable is `null`.

I don't know why you are getting the Exception you show, I didn't when I tried to reproduce it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Jay.

Comment: @Yatrix Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `Where` method

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row=>row["Value"].ToString()).Where(row => row["value"].ToString() == "123");
```

Comment: Well, I thought I'd have to convert the column's value to string. Maybe not. =)

Comment: The lambda in the select is a projection of the result (the `ToString`) and the lambda in the `Where` is a predicate for the result, in other words *what* to return.

Comment: This isn't working. I edited my question, just in case what I wanted wasn't clear.